# Proper way of using environment variables (passed from shell/terminal) in python code

Tags: python, bash, environment-variables

I have a bash shell script (running on Ubuntu 18.04) which reads some input (file or user) and assigns several (environment) variables different values depending on the input. The script launches a program (python) which then, at different points of execution, needs the values that the environment variables have been assigned.

The general approach I'm using so far goes like this

```
# shell script
[...]
export VAR_A = value1
export VAR_B = value2
python program.py
[...]
```

Program consists of several classes which occasionally need the values set in the script.

```
# class1.py, used by program.py
import helper
[...]
var_a = helper.get_var_a()
var_b = helper.get_var_b()
[...]
```

The helper class is used to actually read the environment variable(s).

```
# helper.py
[...]
import os
def get_var_a():
    return os.environ["VAR_A"]
```

The code does what it does correctly. It does however not look "nice" and I doubt that it follows any best practices. What I would like, or am looking for, is a method which either reads the environment variables **once** and stores them in a variable of the program. Something along the lines of the following:

```
# helper.py
# [...]
import os
ENVIRONMENT = { "VAR_A" : os.environ["VAR_A"], "VAR_B" : os.environ["VAR_B"] }
[...]
```

And to get it:

```
# class1.py
var_a = helper.ENVIRONMENT["VAR_A"]
```

**The question:**
Is this (the snippet above) a better or worse approach in turns of:

- Readability/Maintainability
- Code execution/efficiency
- Any other more optimal or "pythonic" alternative?

Comment: Looks like you are trying to re-write os.environ :)

Comment: It's actually arguably *better* to have the program use `os.environ` for retrieving environment variables later on - as it's possible the variables might have changed in the meantime, and you want to use the latest versions

Comment: `os.environ` already contains the environment variables that the process has read. What are you gaining by adding another dictionary on top of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*reads the environment variables once and stores them in a variable of the program*" - that is already done.

Environment variables are held in the process's environment block.  In python these are copied into the dictionary `os.environ` once, when the `os` module is initialised.  The way that the environment block is accessed is not portable, and python shields us from that.

There is specific python code for adding and removing environment variables and updating the environment block when the dictionary is updated.

So there is no point in making another copy of it.

Readability/Maintainability - using *another* variable name would cause confusion.  Worse, if you copied environment variables at the start of your code then altered them, the copy and `os.environ` would be out of step.  Any new values would not be in the environment block and would not be propagated to child processes.

Code execution/efficiency - holding two copies of the same data is always less efficient.  Whether this will be a significant overhead will depend on the size of `os.environ`.

Any other more optimal or "pythonic" alternative?  Yes, use `os.environ`.

Answer (score 1):

helper.py :

```
import os
ENVIRONMENT = os.environ
```

test.py =

```
import helper
print(helper.ENVIRONMENT["hello"])
```

Testing :

```
export hello="world"; python test.py
```

Prints :

```
world
```

... Basically you are trying to create an object that is already implemented : os.environ